# How to create multiple jqgrid instances with jquery?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net

I have been trying jqgrid and is fantastic. After searching a lot, I havent found anything related to this topic, and some help would be great.

I need to create dynamically many jqgrid instances from jquery and append them into a list in html.

My problem is that the navGrid pagination div is not showing the add/edit default buttons, neither custom buttons added manually.

Here is the sample code:

```
function NewgJQGridInstance(houseHoldGridId, gridPlaceholder) {
                //Local variables
                var myGrid = $("<table>").attr("id", houseHoldGridId);
                var myPager = $("<div>").attr("id", houseHoldGridId + "_pager");

                function publicInit() {
                    gridPlaceholder.append(myGrid, myPager);
                    myGrid.jqGrid({
                        datatype: "local",
                        cellsubmit: 'clientArray',
                        height: 100,
                        width: 1300,
                        colModel: [
                            { label: 'Cantidad', name: 'cantidad_menaje', index: 'cantidad_menaje', width: 120, sortable: false, sorttype: "int", editable: true, editrules: { required: true }, editoptions: { size: 10, maxlength: 5 } },
                            { label: 'Menaje', name: 'menaje', index: 'menaje', width: 300, sortable: false, sorttype: "int", editable: true, editrules: { required: true }, editoptions: { size: 50, maxlength: 100 } },
                            { label: 'Observaciones particulares del menaje', name: 'observaciones_menaje', index: 'observaciones_menaje', width: 750, sortable: false, sorttype: "int", editable: true, editrules: { required: true }, editoptions: { size: 10, maxlength: 10 } }
                        ],
                        pager: myPager,
                        loadonce: true,
                        //pgbuttons: false,
                        //pgtext: null,
                        viewrecords: false,
                        loadError: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                            alertError('Error al cargar el grid', 'HTTP message body (jqXHR.responseText): ' + '\n' + jqXHR.responseText);
                        }
                    });
                }
                //Initialization
                return {
                    init: publicInit
                }
            };

            var gridDin = new NewgJQGridInstance("jq1234", cellWhereAppendTheGrid);
            gridDin.init();
```

I have tried several ways of showing the navGrid buttons, but none of them worked for the moment.

My first approach was defining the navGrid pager like this:

```
myGrid.navGrid(myPager,
                    // the buttons to appear on the toolbar of the grid
                    { edit: true, add: true, del: true, search: false, refresh: false, view: false, position: "left", cloneToTop: false },
                    // options for the Edit Dialog
                    {
                        url: 'clientArray',
                        editCaption: "Edición de elemento",
                        recreateForm: true,
                        beforeInitData: function () {
                        },
                        checkOnUpdate: false,
                        checkOnSubmit: false,
                        closeOnEscape: true,
                        beforeSubmit: function (postdata, form, oper) {
                            if (confirm('¿Deseas realmente modificar este registro?')) {
                                // do something
                                return [true, ''];
                            } else {
                                return [false, '¡La modificación no se ha guardado!'];
                            }
                        },
                        closeAfterEdit: true,
                        savekey: [true, 13],
                        errorTextFormat: function (data) {
                            return 'Error: ' + data.responseText;
                        }
                    },
                    // options for the Add Dialog
                    {
                        url: 'clientArray',
                        closeAfterAdd: true,
                        closeOnEscape: true,
                        recreateForm: true,
                        errorTextFormat: function (data) {
                            return 'Error: ' + data.responseText;
                        }
                    },
                    // options for the Delete Dailog
                    {
                        url: 'clientArray',
                        recreateForm: true,
                        closeOnEscape: true,
                        errorTextFormat: function (data) {
                            return 'Error: ' + data.responseText;
                        }
                    });
```

This case was not working, so I tried this other code more simple:

```
myGrid.jqGrid('navGrid', myPager,
                        {
                            edit: true,
                            add: true,
                            del: true,
                            search: false,
                            searchtext: "Buscar",
                            refreshtext: "",
                            addtext: "Add",
                            edittext: "Editar",
                            deltext: "Delete"
                        },
                        {
                            multipleSearch: true
                        });
```

Still no buttons appeared in the navigation pager.

Any idea of what could be wrong?. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Which version of jqGrid is used - Guriddo jqGrid, free-jqGrid or jqGrid <= ver4.7?